Нужен ли знак препинания после "еще пара-тройка лет"
Нужна ли запятая после слов "Ещё пара-тройка лет" в предложении:
Еще пара-тройка лет(,) и ему, мол, умереть не страшно — все можно со спокойным сердцем передавать мне.

Правильно:
Еще пара-тройка лет, и ему, мол, умереть не страшно — все можно со спокойным сердцем передавать мне.
Пояснение

Это сложное предложение, три предикативные основы, сочинительная и бессоюзная связь. По Лопатину здесь два блока, на границе ставится тире. Поэтому в первой части нужно поставить запятую.

Рассмотрим отдельно: Еще пара-тройка лет.  Это неполное предложение  эллиптического характера (обстоятельство + подлежащее), сказуемое "пройдет" пропущено, но оно восстанавливается по второй части.

Обычно в таких случаях ставится тире: Еще пара-тройка лет - и ему, мол, умереть не страшно. Но в данном случае используется запятая, так как  тире ставится перед третьим предложением. Два тире нельзя ставить, да и два сильных знака (тире и двоеточие) тоже нежелательны.


P. S.  В постановке знаков я не сомневаюсь, но грамматика не совсем ясна. С одной стороны предикативность явно присутствует, с другой — предложение не выглядит самостоятельным.  Структура предложения сходна с препозитивным номинативом, то есть она бинарная, но на месте номинатива находится предложение?  Или вы видите здесь другой синтаксис?
Хотелось бы услышать мнение участников, которым интересна грамматика.
P. S.  Впрочем, отвечу сама. Само по себе сочетание номинативное, сравнить: До главных событий оставалась еще пара-тройка лет. Или: Через пару-тройку лет всё может измениться. Но в заданном сложном предложении оно приобретает предикативное значение: пройдет еще пара тройка лет... Поэтому предложение считается сложным, запятая ставится.
